# how can i make selenium code run again and again when it already run finish

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

```
if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'TĂNG LIKE CHO FANPAGE')]")))
{
    string text1 = "like_page";
    this.Job_Like_Fanpage(text1, row_index);
}
else if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT')]")))
{
    string text2 = "like";
    this.Job_Like(text2, row_index);
}
else if (IsElementPresent(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'TĂNG LƯỢT THEO DÕI')]")))
{
    string text3 = "follow";
    this.Job_Follow(text3, row_index);
}
```

it already run in that website . I want it run again again untill a element displayed . Can i use loop . Thanks . C#

Comment: Do you want to search for each xpath multiple times or 3 different xpath's? Also add more context of what you need to understand.

Comment: Look into implicit and explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below code.

```
IWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120))
IWebElement element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("//span[contains(.,'TĂNG LƯỢT THEO DÕI')]|//span[contains(.,'TĂNG LIKE CHO BÀI VIẾT')]|//span[contains(., 'TĂNG LIKE CHO FANPAGE')]")));
```

Comment: OP calling 3 different functions based on xpath. Your xpath would return true even if any one xpath found and which function would he call out of three?

Comment: Yes, This will make sure the script wait until one of the element is present. So Ideally, this will go before the current OP if condition.

Comment: i mean in that website it already run finish . But when it finish i want it run again . again . Untill a element displayed . that is what i want